# Partial derivative of polinomial root

Tags: calculus, polynomials

I have a characteristic equation of the form $P(x,y,z) = 0$. $P$ is a polynomial in $x$ with degree of 3 and is a first order polynomial in $z$.

I computed the value of $x=F(z)$, such that
$$P(F(z),0,z)=0 \quad \textrm{for all }z$$

I wanted to compute $z$ such that 
$$
\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\bigg|_{y=0}=0
$$

Can I do this without specifically solving for $x$?

---

### Example

$$
P(x,y,z)=x^3+[Q+f(y)]zx^2+cy^2f(y)x+cy^2f(y)Qz=0
$$

$$
P(x,0,z)=0 \Rightarrow x=F(z)=-[Q+f(0)]z
$$

Comment: What do you mean?  As you defined it, $x$ does not depend on $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you meant to define $x = F(y,z)$ so that $P(F(y,z),y,z) = 0$ for all $y, z$, and then you want $z$ so that 
$$ \left. \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} F(y,z)\right|_{y=0} = 0 $$ 
Taking the partial derivative of the equation $P(F(y,z),y,z) = 0$ with respect to $y$ at $y=0$ gives you

$$ P_x(F(0,z),0,z) \left.\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} F(y,z)\right|_{y=0} + P_y(F(0,z),0,z) = 0$$

(where subscripts denote partial derivatives)
so that what you need is $P_y(F(0,z),0,z) = 0$.